# Value in C variable disappears

Tags: c, variables

I have a C program that is giving me trouble. It is a plugin for the X-Plane flight simulator. You can view the whole code [here](https://github.com/Nattgew/X-Plane-Plugins/blob/master/oxacars/oxacars.c). The basic function is pulling some information from curl, running and recording information about a flight, and then finally compiling a report of the flight.

The problem is that there is one variable that is misbehaving. I declare it at the beginning of the code because it is needed across multiple functions.

```
char fltno[9];
```

The content is set using a plugin function to get the value from a text box. It takes the value from the `FltNoText` widget, 8 characters long, and assigns it to the `fltno` variable.

```
XPGetWidgetDescriptor( FltNoText, fltno, 8);
```

I build some messages using the following method that include the fltno variable.

```
messg = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "Message stuff %s", fltno) + 1);
sprintf(messg, "Message stuff %s", fltno);
```

This works just fine throughout the running of the program. Right up until the last time it is needed. This is the section that begins with:

```
if (inParam1 == (long)SendButton)
```

This will run at the end. When running this section, the `fltno` variable returns no text. There are many other variables which I am using in the same way, and they all seem to work fine. I ran the program over a short flight and it worked fine, but the two times I have run it on a longer flight, the variable has returned blank in that section.

Let me know if I need to explain more. You can probably tell I haven't written much C so suggestions are appreciated.

**More Info**

It was suggested that the adjacently decalared variables could be overflowing into `fltno`.

The `Ppass[64]` variable is copied from `Ppass_def`, which is set in the code and is definitely smaller than 64.

```
strcpy(Ppass, Ppass_def);
```

The `tailnum[41]` variable is read from a plugin function.

```
XPLMGetDatab( tailnum_ref, tailnum, 0, 40 );
```

Both of these variables are set at the beginning of the program, so it doesn't make sense that `fltno` only misbehaves at the very end.

**Update 1**

Thanks for the comments. As suggested by rodrigo, I replaced the longest `malloc`/`sprintf` instance with calls to some functions. Not sure if what I did is what you had in mind, but it seems to work at least as well as it did before. You can see the new code on the Github link.

I also did more testing and narrowed down a bit where the problem could be. The `fltno` variable is fine when run the last time at line 1193, but by the end of the `case` at line 1278, it is blank. I will try to do more testing later to narrow it down further.

**Update 2**

After more testing I narrowed it down to line 1292. Before that line the `fltno` is fine, after that it becomes blank.

```
strcpy(INlon, dlon);
```

The `dlon` variable is declared within the `if` statement where the `switch` is.

```
char dlon[12];
```

This variable is set every time that section runs, so it's strange that there are no problems until the end. It's set from a function that takes the decimal degrees latitude or longitude and returns a string like "N33 45.9622".

```
strcpy(dlon, degdm(lon, 1));
```

The `INlon` variable is declared at the beginning of the program, and this is the only time it is set.

```
char INlon[12];
```

Any ideas about why this part messes up the `fltno` variable?

**Update 3**

Thanks for the suggestions about `strncpy` and an alternative to the double `sprintf` calls. I changed a few other things and it seems to work now, I will do a full test later to be sure.

A key part that I really should have caught before now is that the latitude/longitude strings were only 12 long, which is too short. When the longitude is over 100 degrees, the string could be "W100 22.5678", which is 12 characters. This caused the end NULL to be cut off and was the source of some of my problems.

```
char INlat[13];
```

I noticed this when I was getting something like "W100 22.5678ABC1234" from those variables, where "ABC1234" is the `fltno` variable.

I used a pointer for `dlat` to avoid size problems, and use `strncpy` to make sure to not spill over to other variables.

```
strncpy(INlat, dlat, sizeof(INlat));
```

Finally, I found the `asprintf` function to replace the double instances of `sprintf`. I understand this won't work on all systems but it's a simple fix for now.

```
char * purl = NULL;
asprintf(&purl, "DATA1=%s&DATA2=%s", DATA1v1, DATA2);
```

So thanks for your help in fixing my code (assuming that it's working now). I feel like I knew enough to be able to fix it (once I was pointed in the right direction) but I'm still not sure exactly what was going on. If anyone wants to post an explanation of what was going wrong (as far as you can tell) I would be happy to accept an answer.

Comment: My bet is that an adjacent variable _(Ppass[64] or tailnum[41])_ is overflowing, or underflowing, it's limit; perhaps overwriting _fltno_.

Comment: I don't understand how `messg = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s") + 1);` is supposed to allocate the memory required to hold `fltno`. Since you know the length of `fltno`, wouldn't it be easier just to declare `messg` with `char messg[8]`, and then, `strcpy(messg, fltno);`??

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Thanks for the tip, I looked at those variables, but they shouldn't change after they are first set in the beginning, I edited with those details.

Comment: @RSahu The messages are much longer and more complicated with more variables, and not just chars. I will see if that method works though.

Comment: All those interminable, almost-but-not quite equal, `printf` statements are making me remember the bad old days... You should really consider writing a few functions here and there...

Comment: @rodrigo Are you referring to all the `snprintf` statements? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Nattgew: Well, there are a few, the best ones are: `char * DATA2 = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%.0f~%.0f~%s~%s~%s~%lu~%lu~%lu~%lu~%.0f~%.0f~%.0f~%s~%s~%.0f~%s~%s~%.0f~%.0f~%.0f~%.0f~%.0f", PID, Ppass, fltno, Type, Alt, Plan, Dep, Arr, Altn, DT, blocktime, flighttime, BF, FF, pax, cargo, online, OUT_time, OFF_time, ON_time, IN_time, ZFW, TOW, LW, OUTlat, OUTlon, OUTalt, INlat, INlon, INalt, maxC, -maxD, maxI, maxG) + 1); sprintf(DATA2, "%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%.0f~%.0f~%s~%s~%s~%lu~%lu~%lu~%......` just 2 lines but too long for a SO comment.

Comment: @Nattgew: Your `realloc()` calls are also suspicious. That is, you check if they fail, but then you go on using the old buffer as if you had enough space. Probably not your original problem, though...

Comment: If you have more details, best to edit your question.

Comment: actually using a pointer to a buffer that is realloced is UB, and the compiler can totally do whatever it wants...

Comment: A way to check for other variables overflowing into `fltno` is to replace it with `struct F { char x1; char fltno[9]; char x2; F(): x1('x'), x2('x') {} };  F f; char (&fltno)[9] = f.fltno;` . Then when reading `fltno` check the `'x'` are still in place. (you could add a reader function that does this and breaks or throws if they aren't).

Comment: @Nattgew the duplicated `sprintf` lines are extremely bad style, you could easily have a typo in one that you miss . Instead you should make  a single function call to allocate the right amount of space and do the printing. (or use a large-sized fixed global buffer).

Comment: Why not `strncpy` or something else that enforces bounds checking?  That might at least give you more confidence about the exact location.

Comment: @Michael thank you for suggesting `strncpy`. I used that for all of the instances where it acts on the latitude/longitude variables. It solves the problem with `fltno` being overwritten, but now the latitude/longitude variables look strange. I will investigate this now.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I will look into a function to allocate and print, thanks for the suggestion.